# Part of specified graph is missing

Tags: pgfplots

I have the code to graph a rational function f(x)=(3x^{2}+5x)/(2x-3) with a vertical asymptote and a slant asymptote. The equation for the vertical asymptote is x=3/2. I decided to have two parts to the domain: one on the interval [-15, 1.4] and one on the interval [1.6, 22]. f(1.4)=-64.4 and f(1.6)=78.4.

Near the vertical asymptote, the smallest and biggest the function gets is about -17 and 34.5, respectively.  I use the commands `ymin=-23,ymax=40` and `restrict y to domain=-23:40` though. Why isn't the graph drawn down to -23 and up to 40?  (I understand that part of the graph near 3/2 would be missing.)  Points on the graph are plotted with coordinates less than -17 or more than 35; these points are far from the vertical asymptote.

By the way, the command `ymin=-23,ymax=40` instructs TikZ to only plot those points (on the graph of the rational function and the two lines) with coordinates between -23 and 40. Doesn't the command `restrict y to domain=-23:40` do the same thing?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Labels At Tip/.style={
        xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},xshift=1.5ex,yshift=-1.5ex, anchor=center},
        ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)},xshift=1.5ex,yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center}
        }
        }


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=7in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-20,xmax=25,
    domain=-20:25, samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-23,ymax=40,
    restrict y to domain=-23:40,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
%    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty}
    Axis Labels At Tip
]
\addplot[samples=251,domain=-15:1.4] {(3*x^2+5*x)/(2*x-3)} node[left,pos=0.15]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{3x^{2}+5x}{2x-3}$};
\addplot[samples=251,domain=1.6:22] {(3*x^2+5*x)/(2*x-3)};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-17:25] {(3/2)*x+5/2} node [pos=0.95, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$y=\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-23:40] (1.5,x) node [pos=0.05, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=\frac{3}{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a few asymptotes.  Have you tried increasing the number of samples you're taking?

Comment: `ymin`/`ymax` sets the limits of the axis, and any part of the plot that is outside will be drawn, then cropped away, as they are outside the axis limits. `restrict y to domain` will cause any parts of the plot outside that domain to not be drawn at all.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. When viewing the pdf file, what is the difference between using `ymin=-23,ymax=40` and `restrict y to domain= -23:40`? Will I get the same graph using only `ymin=-23,ymax=40` and remove the `restrict` command compared to using only `restrict y to domain= -23:40` and removing `ymin= -23,ymax=40`?                                                   In either case, why are parts of the graph missing near the vertical asymptote? On the left side, the graph should be drawn down to -23 and on the right side, the graph should be drawn up to 40.

Comment: Just try it, you'll see if there's a difference. However, note that you have `clip=false`, so the axis limits will *not* crop the plot lines.  The last problem is basically the same as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201048/modifying-some-features-on-the-graphs-of-a-function-and-its-inverse/201058#201058 (Did you ask that question as well?) Adding more samples or changing the domain are possible ways of solving that.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I just increased the number of points plotted from 101 to 201: `domain=-20:25, samples=201`.  The graph is the same.

Comment: You have `samples=251` in the `\addplot` options, that overrides the settings in the axis options. Try something like 1000.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I added `domain=-15:1.23` to the piece of the domain of the rational function to the left of the vertical asymptote. f(1.23) is about -20.

Comment: Yes, that would be the other option. Could we close as duplicate of the question I mentioned earlier, or should I write an answer?

Comment: Will it be kept on the database? The question may be similar to the other question that was posted but our discussion may be of some help to other users.

Comment: @Adelyn: Yes, closed questions are kept in the database and will be linked to from the duplicate question.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  How do I do that?

Comment: Close as duplicate? You can't do that yourself, users with more than 3000 reputation points can vote to close questions.